# Не отображается количество товаров в категориях в главном меню ocStore 2.3

Tags: php, opencart, ocstore

возникла такая проблема. Движок: ocStore 2.3.0.2.3.
В главном меню необходимо выводить количество товаров в категории.
Пр.:
Ноутбуки (452)
Смартфоны (122).
При редактировании header.php (/catalog/controller/common) смог добиться только отображения кол-ва всех товаров.
Код header.php:

```
        // Menu
    $this->load->model('catalog/category');

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $data['categories'] = array();

    $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category['top']) {
            // Level 2
            $children_data = array();

            $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $filter_data = array(
                    'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                    'filter_sub_category' => true
                );

                $children_data[] = array(
                    'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                );
            }

            // Level 1
            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'     => $category['name'],
                'children' => $children_data,
                'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
            );
        }
    }

    $data['language'] = $this->load->controller('common/language');
    $data['currency'] = $this->load->controller('common/currency');
    $data['search'] = $this->load->controller('common/search');
    $data['cart'] = $this->load->controller('common/cart');
```

При замене строки `'name'  =>  $category['name'],` на `'name' => $category['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_prod﻿uct_﻿count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data) . ')' : ''),` отображается количество товаров во всём магазине. При использовании getTotalProducts($filter_data) появляется ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вывел.

Получается, что дополнил

```
'name'  => $category['name'],
```

на

```
'name'     =>﻿ $category['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
```

Потом перед

```
$data['categories'][] = array(
```

добавил

```
$filter_data = array(
                'filter_category_id'  => $category['category_id'],
                'filter_sub_category' => true
            );
```

Вот готовый код, если кому-то понадобится:
P.S. Скорость загрузки сайта такая же.

// Menu
        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

```
    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $data['categories'] = array();

    $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $children_data = array();
        if ($category['top']) {
            // Level 2

            $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $filter_data = array(
                    'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                    'filter_sub_category' => true
                );

                $children_data[] = array(
                    'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                );
            }
            $filter_data = array(
                'filter_category_id'  => $category['category_id'],
                'filter_sub_category' => true
            );
            // Level 1
            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'     => $category['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                'children' => $children_data,
                'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
            );
        }
    }

    $data['language'] = $this->load->controller('common/language');
    $data['currency'] = $this->load->controller('common/currency');
    $data['search'] = $this->load->controller('common/search');
    $data['cart'] = $this->load->controller('common/cart');
```